# Compiling protobufs for C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-csharp-port

For compilations into C# files, all our .proto files contain lines like this:

```
option (google.protobuf.csharp_file_options).namespace = "com.test.foo.SomeClass";
```

I'd like to use these proto files for java too (I have the requisite java_package option set), but if I compile I get all sorts of errors.  Removing this csharp stuff results in fine compilation for Java.

Is there anyway I can use the same files to compile for C# and Java?

Using proto2, and protoc 2.5 and protobuf-java 2.5

EDIT: Here's some of the Java compilations errors:

```
com.test.foo.protobuf.CSharpOptions cannot be resolved to type
com.test.foo.protobuf.CSharpOptions cannot be resolved to a variable
```

EDIT2: The build process is just a script that runs this:

```
${PROTOC} -I=/absolute/path/to/proto --java_out=src/main/java /absolute/path/to/proto/*.proto
```

EDIT3: Here's a quick example. Here's my directory structure:

```
[~/source/shared/example]$ find .
.
./Contact.proto
./google
./google/protobuf
./google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
./google/protobuf/csharp_options.proto
```

csharp_options.proto and descriptor can be [found here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/source/browse/protos/google/protobuf/?r=904dc238ae72f748a142c82b41ffef1d858acc25).

Here's the contents of Contact.proto:

```
package Example.Data.ProtocolBuffer;

import "google/protobuf/csharp_options.proto";
option java_package = "com.example.data.protobuf";
option java_outer_classname = "ContactProto";

option (google.protobuf.csharp_file_options).namespace = "Example.Data.ProtocolBuffer.Contact";

message Contact {
        required string name = 1;
        required string address = 2;
        repeated int32 rank = 3;
}
```

Upon executing the protoc script (See Edit 2), it creates the following:

```
[~/source/prototest]$ find .
.
./src
./src/main
./src/main/java
./src/main/java/com
./src/main/java/com/example
./src/main/java/com/example/data
./src/main/java/com/example/data/protobuf
./src/main/java/com/example/data/protobuf/ContactProto.java
```

Currently I'm just using Eclipse for compilation. (No maven yet). In eclipse it reports the following compiler errors:

```
google cannot be resolved   ContactProto.java   
google cannot be resolved to a variable ContactProto.java
```

Here's the offending code:

```
    ...
    com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry = com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry.newInstance();
registry.add(google.protobuf.CsharpOptions.csharpFileOptions); //compiler error
              return registry;
            }
          };
        com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor
          .internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(descriptorData,
            new com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.FileDescriptor[] {
              google.protobuf.CsharpOptions.getDescriptor(), //compiler error
            }, assigner);
      }
```

As you can see it expects CsharpOptions to be present, but it is not.

Comment: Can you provide the error output?

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Edited the question and included some compilation errors.

Comment: Can you add more details about your build process? How are you invoking protoc? Any errors there? Provide complete error output - more is better. Also check the version of protobuf-java that you're using.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Thanks for the response. I'm just running a simple shell script (edited question to include it). There's no error output when I run it.  protoc --version returns "libprotoc 2.5.0".

Comment: I was speaking of the java build process as well. You need to check the library that java is using, which is distinct from protoc (though you need to be sure they match up). For example, if you were building your java project with maven, it would be in the dependencies section of `pom.xml`.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy, Sorry, I misunderstood. I'm just using Eclipse. Additionally, in Edit3 above, I created a small example which may better illustrate the problem.

Comment: Your csharpOptions are in google.protobuf, not COM.google.protobuf. What's the java_package declared in csharp_options.proto? That's what will determine the fully qualified name in java, not the directory structure where the proto files happen to be. (but the inter-proto references DO depend on the directory structure)

Comment: @CaptainMurphy I highlighted where the compiler errors just to be extra clear. I'm using exactly what's been [given here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/source/browse/protos/google/protobuf/csharp_options.proto?r=904dc238ae72f748a142c82b41ffef1d858acc25)  which has no java_package. I've tried with a java_package of com.google.protobuf and google.protobuf, but it makes no difference; I get the same kinds of errors.

Comment: It really seems like we either want a) the generated java files to ignore csharpoptions or b) a generated a java file for csharpoptions but for it to basically affect nothing in the code. Neither seems plausible.  @JonSkeet would you be able to offer any additional insight?